# Python Winsock - How to send data through an already active winsock connection

Tags: python, winsock, ping, irc

The script I have is written in a different language unfamiliar to most people [MQL4] but I've imported python functionality into the code so I can execute python code inside the script. My problem is, I'm connecting to a server with MQL4 and I want to send data through its stream using python. So far, I can only get python to create its own connection. Is there anyway to connect to a windows socket that's already opened?

THE MQL CODE

```
void ircconnect(){
int struct_sockaddr[4];
int addr, port_low, port_high;
int opts[1];
int c;

if (irc_disabled == 1) return(0);

// fill the sockaddr struct
addr = inet_addr(server_addr);
port_low = server_port & 0x00ff;
port_high = (server_port & 0xff00) >> 8; 
struct_sockaddr[0] = AF_INET | (port_high << 16) | (port_low << 24);
struct_sockaddr[1] = addr;
struct_sockaddr[2] = 0;
struct_sockaddr[3] = 0;

// connect
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

opts[0] = 1000; // send timeout milliseconds
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, opts, 4);

c = connect(s, struct_sockaddr, 16);
```

THE PYTHON CODE

```
//Initialize Python Dll
PyInit();
PyExecute("from Tkinter import *");
PyExecute("root = Tk()");   

//Import necessary modules
PyExecute("import socket, os");

//Connect
PyExecute("network = \"irc.ircnetwork.com\"");
PyExecute("port = 6667");
PyExecute("irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)");
PyExecute("irc.connect((network, port))");

//Identify
PyExecute("irc.recv(1024)");
PyExecute("irc.send(\\"NICK Nick\\r\\n\")");
PyExecute("irc.send(\\"USER Nick Nick Nick :Nick IRC\\r\\n\")");
PyExecute("irc.send(\\"JOIN #channel\\r\\n\")");
PyExecute("irc.send(\"PRIVMSG NickServ IDENTIFY <pass>\\r\\n\")");
PyExecute("VERSION = \"version>\\r\\n\"");

//Listen for PING
PyExecute("while True:");
PyExecute("data = irc.recv(1024)");
PyExecute("print data");
PyExecute("if data.find(\"PING\") != -1:");

//Send PONG
PyExecute("irc.send(\"PONG \" + data.split() [ 1 ] + \"\\r\\n\")");
PyExecute("elif data.find(\"VERSION\") !=-1:");
PyExecute("irc.send(VERSION + \"\\r\\n\")");
PyExecute("elif data.find(\"NOTICE\") !=-1:");
PyExecute("nick = data.split(\"\!\") [ 0 ].replace (\":\", \"\" )");
PyExecute("message = \":\".join( data.split (\":\") [ 2: ] )");
```

Comment: possibly of interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: FYI, Python strings can use single quotes as well, eliminating having to escape double quotes so much in the code.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes.

It is both possible and recommendable.

Than your MQL code can "speak" to whatever counterparty -- be it `Python`, `java`, `C#/C++`, `PHP`, ..., `Erlang`, ... counterparty.

Do not risk troubles and issues with raw O/S sockets, rather use a way higher abstraction like **ZeroMQ**, that has **MQL4ZMQ** bindings ported and published by Austen Conrad,